# MemoryError when attempting to create a docker image with Torch/PyTorch

Tags: python, docker, flask, pip, pytorch

I am following [this tutorial](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html) to create a Docker image for a flask application. The application depends on Torch/PyTorch. As such, my `requirements.txt` file looks like the following.

```
flask
flask-cors
pytorch
torchvision
pandas
```

My Dockerfile then looks like the following.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL My Company "info@mycompany.com"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -vvv --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

When I type in the command `docker build -t flask-sample-one:latest .` I get the following error message (which happens when pip is trying to install torch) on my Mac.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
    self._close()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 55, in dumps
    "body": _b64_encode_bytes(body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 12, in _b64_encode_bytes
    return base64.b64encode(b).decode("ascii")
MemoryError
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -vvv -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am not sure what the `MemoryError` is coming from. I tried to build the docker image on a Macbook Pro with 16 GB of RAM. Any ideas on what's going on or how to create a docker image with Python?

On an AWS EC2 instance, I get the following error.

```
Running setup.py install for pytorch: started
    Running command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5jxyuS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/setup.py", line 13, in 
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org
    Running setup.py install for pytorch: finished with status 'error'
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5jxyuS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 360, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 725, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5jxyuS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SeBh33/pytorch/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -vvv --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any ideas on what's going on? I am simply trying to build a docker image with those few dependencies so I can serve a PyTorch model from a flask application. I'm not sure if there's a tutorial out there on doing this (couldn't find one yet).

Comment: Docker for Mac doesn’t use all the system memory; try (Whale), Preferences, Advanced to increase the available memory (there is a hidden Linux VM).  pytorch.org suggests you should be installing a package named `torch`, not `pytorch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I was able to get `PyTorch` installed into a docker container as follows.

I modified the `requirements.txt` to look like the following.

```
flask
flask-cors
pandas
```

I then modified `Dockerfile` to look like the following. It's quirky and does not follow the conventional way of install Python packages with pip, but it works. Note that I have to install Python 3, followed by PyTorch wheel, and then finally with a pip install of `torchvision`.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL My Company "info@mycompany.com"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -vvv --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
RUN pip3 install torchvision
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```